# Can I add c# DLL files into the iPad application(Native Xcode- objective C)?

Tags: c#, objective-c, iphone

I have some set of algorithms in a c# class library and I have a dll for this class library. Can I add this dll into the iPad application  and access those algorithms from iPad application?

Comment: If it's pure .NET (not utilizing Win32 or other API), you might create a new app in [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/platform). If you really need to adapt the existing iPad app, either host the DLL in a webservice, or port the code into Objective C